# How to evaluate $\sum_{k=2}^\infty (11k + 7)(k+1)\frac{M^{2k+1}}{(M+N)^{2k+4}}$ as a integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation

There is a summation like this,
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty (11k + 7)(k+1)\frac{M^{2k+1}}{(M+N)^{2k+4}}$$
There is a condition that $\frac{N}{M}\ll 1$.

How to replace the summation over $k$ to an integral and come up with the answer $\frac{11}{4N}$.

I checked this answer using Mathematica and it is correct but can't figure how to convert it to an integral and perform the calculation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of the series as $M$ goes to infinity and $N>0$ is
$$\lim_{M\to +\infty}\sum_{k=2}^\infty (11k + 7)(k+1)\frac{M^{2k+1}}{(M+N)^{2k+4}}=\dfrac{11}{4N^3}.$$

Let $x=(M/(M+N))^2$ then, as $M$ goes to infinity, 
$$x=\frac{1}{(1+N/M)^2}=1-\frac{2N}{M}+O(1/M^2)$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty (11k + 7)(k+1)\frac{M^{2k+1}}{(M+N)^{2k+4}}&=
\frac{x^2}{M^3}\sum_{k=2}^\infty (11k^2 + 18k+7)x^k\\
&\sim
\frac{11}{M^3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2x^k=
\frac{11}{M^3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2e^{k\ln(x)}\\
&\sim
\frac{11}{N^3}\cdot\frac{N}{M}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{kN}{M}\right)^2e^{-\frac{2kN}{M}}\\&\to\frac{11}{N^3}\int_0^{\infty}t^2e^{-2t}\,dt=\frac{11}{4N^3}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you please explain me the last step where you convert the sum into an integral. Are there any theories used for that?

Comment: The series is related to a Riemann sum of the integral. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that
>   $\ds{\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}
> \pars{11k + 7}\pars{k + 1}\,{M^{2k + 1} \over \pars{M + N}^{\, 2k + 4}} =
> {1 \over M^{3}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
> \pars{11k + 29}\pars{k + 3}\xi^{k}}$
>   
>   $\ds{= {11\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k^{2}\xi^{k} +
> 62\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}k\xi^{k} +
> 87\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\xi^{k} \over M^{3}}\quad}$ where
>   $\ds{\quad\xi \equiv {1 \over \pars{1 + N/M}^{2}}}$

\begin{align}
&\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}\xi^{k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{\xi^{2} \over 1 - \xi} = -1 - \xi + {1 \over 1 - \xi}}
\\
\ds{\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}k\,\xi^{k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\xi + {\xi \over \pars{1 - \xi}^{2}} = -\xi - {1 \over 1 - \xi} + {1 \over \pars{1 - \xi}^{2}}}
\\
\ds{\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}k^{2}\,\xi^{k}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\xi + {\xi \over \pars{1 - \xi}^{2}} + \color{red}{2\xi \over \pars{1 - \xi}^{3}}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> $\ds{N/M \to 0 \implies \xi \to 1}$ such that the original sum becomes

$$
\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \xi\ \to\ 1}{\sim}\,\,\,
{11 \over M^{3}}\,\color{red}{2 \over \pars{1 - \xi}^{3}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N/M\ \to\ 0}{\sim}\,\,\,
{11 \over M^{3}}\,{2 \over \pars{2N/M}^{3}} = \bbx{{11 \over 4N^{3}}}
$$